# Sending automated text messages from web.skype.com, using Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-ide, skype

I’m trying to send automated text messages from *Skype* web client, using *Selenium*.

So far, I was able to authenticate myself and select the required unique recipient. It works fine both programmatically (*Java* bindings) and using *Selenium IDE*.
But I was not able to successfully add text to the message box. And without that, *Skype* does not even shows the send button!

In a recent past, I googled that one could send  a message with something like:

```
input_messages = browser.find_element_by_name('messageInput')
input_messages.send_keys('Testing Output' + Keys.RETURN)
```

But I guess *Microsoft* changed the web client as this does not work anymore, namely by not showing the “Send” button unless something is written in the message box:

[image]
[image]

Using *Selenium IDE*, it records this set of commands (*Skype* authentication omitted):

[image]

However, running above script, I get what seems to be an overlapped “Test” string on top of original “Type a message”:

[image]

It seems obvious to me that *Selenium IDE* is not placing my “Test” string in the “right” place. And because of that, not even the send button is shown.

Here’s the “edit content” parameters:

**Target**

```
css=.notranslate

xpath=//div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div
```

**Value**

```
<div data-contents="true"><div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="f244q" data-offset-key="0-0-0"><div data-offset-key="0-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"><span data-offset-key="0-0-0"><span data-text="true">Test</span></span></div></div></div>
```

And the Chrome Inspect of the message box:
[image]

So, any idea what Selenium IDE (or myself…) is doing wrong?...

What is the right locator and how to edit its content (to set my text message), making sure the send button is then shown and clickable (though a Keys.ENTER should then suffice).

Thank you in advance!

---

```
Windows 10 - 1903 (64-bit)
Google Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Selenium IDE 3.17.0
chromedriver_win32-85.0.4183.87
selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problems and tried many methods:

1. clear the element before sendkeys
2. sendkeys multiple times in for-loop

I can’t tell which method is effective, so I will give you a code snippet in my real project.

```java
// for the div element

boolean bl = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    element.clear();
    element.sendKeys(text);
    if (element.getText().equals(text)) {
        bl = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it only worked for me… a few sometimes. These are my findings:
1) Most of the time (i.e., most of the executed tests), it just overlaps text (as described) and your suggestion simply doesn’t work (even when trying more than 3 times and introducing some pauses (`Thread.sleep(pause_ms));`) in between.
2)Surprisingly enough, it worked a few - non-repeatable - (random) times.

Comment: Anyway, `if (element.getText().equals(text))` just didn’t work:
 a) It returned true even when I could not send any text;
 b) It returned false (typically skipping “my_msg” first character) and I was still able to send the entire message!

Moreover, even though not part of the scope of my original question, sometimes my message recipient fails (usually by choosing a nearby – wrong- one).

This is really frustrating as it seems to me that web.skype.com sometimes changes object ids between executions, thus invalidating any automation effort…

Any ideas how to proceed?